# Save Value to List from Stream

Tags: java

Currently im learning about stream and want to implement a method which accepts a string. The String starts with a certain word and ends with the same. The given example is "breadtunabread". The method return the word in between the bread.

```
public String getTopping(String s){
    Stream<String> stream = Stream.of(s);
    stream.filter(t -> t.startsWith("bread") && t.endsWith("bread")).
    forEach(t -> Stream.of(t.split("bread")[1]).collect(Collectors.toList()));
}
```

I'd like to either save it to a List or change it directly so it returns a String.
Is it possible to get the first value from the stream and not use collect?
I somehow made it work using forEach and adding the value to an ArrayList and returning it but i'd like to know whether there is a way to do it directly using the stream.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You don't need `Stream`s for this at all. Don't try to make things unnecessarily fancy.

Answer (score 2):

And to return just a String:

```
public String getTopping(String s, String toReplace) {
    Stream<String> stream = Stream.of(s);
    return stream.filter(t -> t.startsWith(toReplace) && t.endsWith(toReplace))
            .findFirst()
            .map(t -> t.replaceAll(toReplace, ""))
            .orElseThrow(RuntimeException::new);
            //.orElseThrow(() -> new NoBreadException("s"));
}
```

Comment: Thanks. That solved my problem. When i want to throw a custom Exception, lets say NoBreadException(String topping), how i do that?
I tried orElseThrow(NoBreadException(s)::new); but it didnt work.
orElseThrow(new NoBreadException(s)); didnt work either

Comment: Hi @lkaros2205, it should be done like this: .orElseThrow(() -> new NoBreadException(s)), assuming that you have a proper constructor for your exception.

Comment: I've edited my answer with that part. In java, when you use lambda expression, you use syntax ((Type reference) -> do work with reference). When there are no references required, you just do (() -> do work).

Comment: And your attempt orElseThrow(NoBreadException(s)::new) did not work because method reference cannot take arguments, they simply try to get them from the context, and in context of no arguments (which .orElseThrow takes) there is no way to supply something.

Answer (score 1):

Just like @Naman pointed out, you don't need a Stream for this. String#replaceAll will quite literally replace all instances of the String (bread) with empty String values and in the end you get you're topping. Added the base parameter in case you're a monster like me and eat cheese between pieces of ham.

```java
    public static String getTopping(String value, String base) {
        return value.replaceAll(base, "");
    }
```

```java
    String topping = getTopping("breadtunabread", "bread")
```

### Assuming you have a List of items you want to get the toppings of.

```java
        List<String> sandwhiches = Arrays.asList(
                "breadtunabread",
                "breadchickenbread",
                "breadcheesebread",
                "breadturkeybread",
                "breadlambbread"
        );

        List<String> toppings = sandwhiches.stream()
                .map(sandwhich -> getTopping(sandwhich, "bread"))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Result

```
[tuna, chicken, cheese, turkey, lamb]
```

Comment: Interesting. The thing is that im trying to understand streams so that curesthe symptome but not the source.
I tried it like this.

String list = stream.filter(t -> t.startsWith("bread") && t.endsWith("bread")).
map(t -> Stream.of(t.split("bread")[1]).collect(Collectors.toList())).findFirst();

The error message is that i could get an empty list with Strings since i filter.

Comment: Do you have a List of String values that represent many different sandwhiches? If so, feel free to edit your question with that and then I can update my answer.

Comment: Somewhat. Its either breadSomethingbread or just the Topping. So it could be breadabcdebread.
Right now i only use one String instead of a list of Strings. But i thought that i could use streams and the filter function on a single String instead of a list of Strings

Comment: Stream of String doesn't make any sense. Streams are for operating more than one entry. If you had a method that took many String objects and got all the toppings from them then it would make sense.

Comment: Thank you. That really helped

Comment: Awesome! Glad to hear :)

Answer (score 1):

```
Stream<String> stream = Stream.of("breadtunabread");
List<String> stringList =
    stream
        .filter(t -> t.startsWith("bread") && t.endsWith("bread"))
        .map(t -> (t.split("bread")[1]))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Is this what you are looking for?
What others mentioned are correct that this is completely unnecessary. I posted this as you have mentioned that yuo are learning streams.

Comment: I tried this but i got an error message saying that a List cant be paramterized with Aruguments <String>

Comment: Thanks. Somehow Eclipse imported awt.list instead of util.list